# Blocking BLE Chip Antenna from picking up signals in one direction

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, antenna, bluetooth-low-energy, pcb-antenna

I am designing a BLE scanner/observer which uses a ceramic antenna.

I was wondering if there is any way to design the PCB such that the antenna chip only picks up signals from in front of it instead of omnidirectional signal pickup? (for example, maybe have a live 2.8V plane in the bottom layer under the antenna which is on the first layer?)

[image]

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: I only want it to detect signals from the front due to it being in multiple rooms so i can detect which room the signal was detect at. This will be mounted on a wall/ceiling so I dont want it to pick up signals from outside the room. It detects a specific beacon name to trigger a relay.

Comment: My limited knowledge of antennas would say no, just for the fact that you're going to get a lot of reflections on other objects. Also changing the antenna pattern could also violate FCC specs

Comment: Do those RFID blocking fabrics work? Did anyone try blocking Bluetooth signals from one direction with it?
Like these:
[link](https://www.amazon.com.au/gp/product/B018298ZLG/ref=ppx_od_dt_b_asin_title_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Comment: unidirectional antennae do exist, and do roughly what you want (although the directivity may not be as good as you want) - I dont know if you can easily do anything to a chip antenna to make it more directional

Comment: https://abracon.com/datasheets/APAKN2504-S2448-T.pdf might work for you, take a look at page 2

Comment: I dont need to change the antenna was wondering if any changes in the PCB design can help me achieve it.

Comment: @BeB00 Thank you for the suggestion. I am not very informed about antennas but from what i see in the documentation, my understanding is that there is still pickup in the -z and because I am reading beacons that are in the 2m to 3m range I feel like there would be pickup of beacons behind the antenna as well.

Am i correct in what I am saying?

Comment: @YudiNZ there will always be some level of signal receivable from every direction, what matters is the amount of attenuation. Your device would look at the signal strength of the devices it sees, and filter out devices with less than a certain strength. Will this be perfect? No, definitely not. Will it be good enough? Maybe, that's up to you. The proper way to do this would be to try to find an even more directive antenna (might be tricky) or use Bluetooth Direction Finding, assuming your IC supports it (https://www.bluetooth.com/learn-about-bluetooth/recent-enhancements/direction-finding/)

Comment: @YudiNZ Fundamentally, the problem you are trying to solve is location tracking (to some degree) using bluetooth, and this is not a simple problem. There are different ways that it can be done, and none of these is perfect.

Comment: You're saying that you want directivity (direction sensitivity) but you chose to use an omnidirectional antenna... Use a directional antenna. And no, those won't be PCB-mount. They'll be something you can either hold in your hand and connect by a cable, or mount on a threaded connector.

Comment: @BeB00 thank you for your input and suggestions. Will use the Abracon antenna and check performance. Also will let you know what my results are like if you are interested.

Also, Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica unfortunately I am not very informed regarding antennas as this is my first time working with them. Thank you for your suggestion but as stated above I will use the patch antenna and report back. This is also because I don't have much area to work with hence this solution.